# PHP Conditional for html code block not quite working - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

My goal is that I am only wanting a child menu to show on certain pages.

```
<?php if ( $post->post_parent == 'gallery' || $post->ID == 72 || $post->ID == 77) : ?>
<nav id="childnavtop">
    <div class="maxwidth">
    <ul>
        <?php $childnavargs=array('child_of' => get_top_ancestor_id(), 'title_li' => '');?>
        <?php wp_list_pages($childnavargs);?>
</ul>
</div><!--/.maxwidth-->
</nav><!--/.childnavtop-->

<?php else : ?>
    <span>testing to see if it works.</span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The first conditional statement isn't quite working.  I don't want any of the html code to show up.  The menu appears and disappears on specific pages as I want, but the html code for  still shows up on every page.  I figure that I am not gracefully getting in and out of PHP properly.  How can I get the entire block of html to not show up?

Comment: Actually you are switching between HTML and PHP properly which I don't see very often

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($post->post_parent)` and `print_r($post->ID)`?

Comment: First thank you for replying,  it is so hard to get help for issues like this. 
 FYI, This is only a test site, so it only has six pages and two child pages under gallery.  I am surprised that  I had already looked at your question, and it displays the expected "0" for all top level pages, 50 for the gallery page and 73 and 77 for the child pages.  Still the main problem is that I expected for all of the "childnav" html elements to completely be gone unless the condition is true.  The menu indeed disappears, but the childnav div wrappers still show up.  Can't understand why this is happening.

Comment: I thought I stumbled onto the answer, but I was wrong!!!!  I changed $post->post_parent == 'gallery'  to post_parent == 'gallery' and it seemed to work as expected, but after fully refreshing the page, it just broke the script.

Comment: This finally worked, but I don't understand why the other version kind of didn't:  <?php if ( has_children() OR $post->post_parent > 0 ) { ?>
Code to execute goes here.  <?php } ?>